# Error: Initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

Getting another error with my string class.  The intellisense will not let me use strcmp to compare an object with the self-invoking object (i.e. *this).

I tried making my own operator conversion function to help with this, but it is still giving me the error.

What do I have to change in my code to make this work??

```
//Overloaded comparison operators
bool &String::operator<(const String & obj)
{
    return strcmp(*this, obj) < 0 ? true : false;
}

//Operator conversion function
String::operator char const * () const
{
    return mStr;
}
```

Comment: Why return a `bool&` from this, it makes no sense. Just return a `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a reference to a local variable. Return by value. You can also simplify the return expression, and make the method `const`, since comparing two objects should not change either of them:

```
bool String::operator<(const String & obj) const {
  return strcmp(*this, obj) < 0;
}
```

<strike>although I am not sure `strcmp` can deal with two `String`s, which is what you are passing it. Judgning from your previous question, you need</strike>

```
return strcmp(mstr, obj.mStr) < 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it `const` and remove `&`

```
bool String::operator<(const String & obj) const
                                           ^^^^^
```

Returning references to temporary objects leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The error message explicitly points to first parameter of `strcmp()`, *this is a rvalue, but strcmp requires a lvalue, try to add one sentence before:

```
String thisObj = *this;
```

Comment: why? can you tell more ?

Comment: `*this` is not an rvalue.  In particular, you know its address (which is `this`).  The rvalue is the temporary created by the implicit call to `String::operator char const *() const`.